# Symfony/twig turn off cache

Tags: symfony, twig

I've currently come into a job that uses Symfony2 and it's simple enough, but I've never used Symfony and I cannot find out how to turn off twig template caching. I need to make changes to the view as I go along and this is preventing me from doing so. In my config.yaml file I have the following entry for twig:

```
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: you should call app_dev.php to get in the development environment.

Answer (score 5):

You have to switch to the dev environment where the caching is disabled. Open your controller with `app_dev.php`.

`http://www.test.de/app_dev.php/`

Then the caching is disabled and you can test your changes.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html

Comment: Thx. I've added that link to my answer :)

Comment: thanx guys. So www.mysite.com/app_dev.php? I get 'You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.'

Comment: You have to be on localhost. Or uncomment the line in the app_dev.php.

Comment: No app_dev file for some reason. Guess I'll scrap developing on server and set up WAMP. I guess Phil Karlton was right.

Comment: Why would you ever want to develop on the live server?